# Can I ask multiple programming languages in one Stack Overflow question?

Tags: discussion, questions, code-languages

Let's say I have a project from a client that requires using multiple languages for a few of logic. For example:

> How can I build the addition function in C++, Java, JavaScript, and Python?

Answer Format:

1. C++

   ```cpp
   #include <iostream>

   int add(int a, int b) {
       // Implementation
   }
   ```
2. Java

   ```java
   public class NewClass {
       public static int add(int a, int b) {
           // implementation
       }
   }
   ```
3. JavaScript

   ```javascript
   function add(a, b) {
       // Implementation
   }
   ```
4. Python

   ```python
   def add(a, b):
       # Implementation
   ```

Is it illegal to ask with this style? What is the best practice?

Comment: My take on this would be "no" as this would make the question 1) very unfocused (a reason to close it) and 2) a work-dump (a reason to down-vote it). Although having said that, much would depend on the specifics of the question and the situation, since surely, your question wouldn't be close to what you've posted above, would it?

Comment: These would be best asked as separate questions. However, I would suggest that instead you focus on *one* language and solve the problems for that. Then you can translate those solutions yourself to other languages. If you then get stuck on a specific translation, you can then ask a similar question for that language.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### One question per question

No, do not ask four questions in the body of one post.

There are exceptions if all questions pertain to the same concept but this is not the case here. Knowing how to do addition in C++ does not necessarily imply anything about addition in Java, or JavaScript, or Python. And vice versa.

### Ask *focused* cross-language questions

You can, however, ask something specific. Not just "how to do this four different ways" but perhaps a better question would be:

> I am trying to add numbers together in C++ and Java but for <some values> in Java I get <incorrect result> instead of what I get in C++ which is <correct result>. How can I adjust the Java code?

or perhaps

> I am trying the same addition code in Python and JavaScript and I get different results in <explain cases>. What rules do the languages have that lead to this different outcome?

Or other questions that are about a specific problem where a single answer does not need several quite different areas of expertise.

Comment: Oftentimes it's simply better to ask "I am trying <some code> and was expecting <result> but got <different result> instead. What am I missing?" Adding another programming language in a question might confuse the readers. Although sometimes the additional context might be useful, so try to use your judgement on whether that extra context would be useful or not.